# How to hide a div by clicking the same toggle button or elsewhere in the document

Tags: jquery, html, document, hide, toggle

Right now I can show a div by clicking a button, and hide it using the same button.  That's working fine, but I would also like a user to be able to click outside of the newly shown div or the button to show it, and still hide it.

Hey guys, this is my first time asking a question here, so I'm sorry if I didn't enter the code right or something.  Basically I have a button, and I want only one way to open a hidden div (clicking said button), but two ways to close it (clicking the same opening button or elsewhere in the document).

Here is my current code.

```
//This part works fine for opening and closing, but you can't click outside the button to make it close once opened.<br/>

$(".account").click(function () {
    $(".accountlinks").toggle();
    $(".account").toggleClass("active");
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('.accountlinks').hide();
    $(".account").removeClass("active");
});

$('.accountlinks').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Is there some way to see if it is already opened, and then close it with the document.click function using this `$('.account').hasClass('active');` in some way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like it could work. Can you check in Firebug/Devtools console if `$('.accountlinks').hide(); $(".account").removeClass("active");` has any effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my approach:  Rather than giving the "active" class to the button, as you appear to be doing, I give it to the div.  That way, you can select open divs in the document click using the "active" class.  Check it out:

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggler").click(function(e) {
        $("#toggled").toggle().toggleClass("active");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $('.active').hide().removeClass('active');
    });

    $("#toggled").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

And here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/xNQN3/

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!  This works perfectly, but I even modified it further so that I can give styles to the button when its opened or closed.

Comment: <code>$(function() {
    $(".account").click(function(e) {
        $(".accountlinks").toggle().toggleClass("open");
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $('.open').hide().removeClass('open');
        $('.account').toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".accountlinks").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});</code> for anyone who is curious of how you can style and get this to work like a dream.  thanks again ender